# Please help me create a puzzle to ask a girl out

Tags: cipher, puzzle-creation

I met a girl and wow! it's like she's my muse (no, I am not an ancient Greek :) ). She inspired me to build an app that will have a simple riddle that will say

> "Θελεις να βγουμε?" ("Do you want to go out with me?" in Greek).

I'm trying to think of a simple math equation that would result in +1, and then having the message be the greek letters that are one position before the letters in my message:

> ηδκδθρ μω αβξτλδ?

where if you take the previous letter from the [Greek Alphabet](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZUrZHF_WBeI/hqdefault.jpg), the intended string will be revealed!

However, I am worried of how to hint to her to do this? I mean, I am in Computer Science and adding 1 from the ASCII code seems obvious to me, but she is not in CS. So how do I hint to her (without actually making it too easy) that the +1 means that she should take the previous letter for every letter in the given string?

If +1 is a bad choice, please suggest a new one!

Comment: I would be very happy if the downvoter suggested how I could improve this question. :)

Comment: How is that a riddle? If I understand you correctly, it's a ROT-1 cipher with the greek alphabet as the charset.

Comment: I don't really think this is a puzzle. If we were asked to solve that riddle it would be, but you seem to have told us the answer and just how we can think up a hint

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It doesn't have to be a puzzle to be on-topic, though.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil and Lukas sorry for the wrong names, but I am not sure about them, I am not good in English.. There was no other tag with the word creation already made...Should I delete the question?

Comment: BTW, I think you mean you have to take the *next* letter to reveal the plaintext.

Comment: @LukasRotter I upvoted your comment, but no, I think -1 was correct. For example the previous letter from theta is eta :P

Comment: @gsamaras I was talking about the decryption process. (I thought that's what you meant, sorry. So dependent on the perspective, both `+1` and `-1` is correct :D)

Comment: But *"So how do I hint to her (without actually making it too easy) that the -1 means that she should take the previous letter for every letter in the given string?"* is still incorrect if you give her the string `ηδκδθρ μω αβξτλδ`, since that means eta would become zeta .

Comment: In English that's also known as a Caesar Cipher http://practicalcryptography.com/ciphers/caesar-cipher/ - maybe there's a Greek equivalent of that name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a rot 1 cipher so you could hint that by saying

> '*Read oh thoughtful one*'

With

> The initials saying ROT and then a 1 on the end. Something like this would work.

If she doesn't know what a ROT cipher is then you could

> Add *your* initials on it instead of your name, to hint at initials. Then she could look it up.

Comment: Assuming she knows what ROT-X ciphers are...

Comment: @Marius added another way